# Denying Access To Oracle Database via tools like Toad, SQL Developer using Request Based Authentication

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad, application-server

I need to restrict access to Oracle Database via tools like Toad, SQL Developer etc.
Only the request coming from Application Server should be allowed to connect successfully.

Comment: Don't give your developers access to production credentials. Problem solved.

Comment: In MySQL, Logon credentials are based on both the user name and host (IP). Is their something like that in Oracle as well ? Can we achieve host based authentication by LOGON trigger in Oracle ?

Comment: You can't rely on the application name because it's the client which supplies that. The only way to ensure this is on the network level.

Comment: You can check `sys_context('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS')` inside logon trigger, but this protection can be easily circumvented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- Restrict access to DB on Firewall level
- Restrict access to DB via Listener configuration (listener.ora)
- Restrict access to DB via logon trigger on schema. You can find templates of such a trigger on the Internet. Basically you have to select from [sys_context](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions165.htm) function(or from *v$session* view). This will tell you all the information you need. Then any exception raised from logon trigger aborts the connection.
- Grant access to users, but do not give them any privs. Then grant necessary privs to password protected role and enable this role via "SET ROLE" *ONLY* from the application.

Or you can mix these approaches as you want.

Comment: It's not entirely clear if the OP wants to prevent access from certain applications (which is not really possible) or from certain machine. This answer covers the second case. (Of course, running SQL Developer or SQL*Plus *from* the application server will bypass all filters.)